# Docker for MAC OSX : Cant access mounted volume

Tags: macos, docker, permissions

I am trying to run a docker container as

```
docker run -d -p 9088:9088 --name abc -h abc -v /some/location:/some/location artifactory/abc
```

`/some/location` has a script that the container will execute. The above command gives me the error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"/some/location/myScript\": stat /some/location/myScript: no such file or directory".
```

but when i do

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9088:9088 --name abc -h abc -v /some/location:/some/location artifactory/abc
```

the container starts up and runs just fine. However I dont want to use sudo as I am not using it for any other containers. I just want to run it as docker. How do i do that? Note that i have

`chmod 777 /some/location`

so why cant docker access `myScript`?

Comment: What is the exact location? don't tell `/some/location/` give exact. Also have you tried similar thing from `~/xyz` which goes from your home directory and see if it works without sudo

Comment: `/some/location` is a folder under root. not tried with anything under `~`

Comment: Try that with the home folder because root folder will need access on parents folder

Comment: how can i grant access to docker?

Comment: I think it has to do with your user not having access to the file. Did you test this using /home/user/myScrip (mac = /Users/Username)t? Does your user have access to the file? Are they in the user:group? If not you could change ownership on the file but for testing you could also just use your home folder.

Comment: You can chown the folder tree to your user. `sudo chown -R youruser /some` to give docker access without sudo.